# Swift array inside struct only appends once how can it append again a separate time?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am making an app that loads a list of books and book categories that the user can add to the table. I have created a struct to organize the data. When the user wants to add a new book or category, it brings up my `AddBookCategoryViewController`. When I try to add a category, it successfully loads the category as a title header. However, when I try to add a second category, it does not add it the second time. It does not bring up any errors, and it passes through the entire `prepareForSegue`. I am at an utter loss at how to figure it out.

Note: Im not trying to add two categories at once, I am trying to add one successfully (which I can), then hit the add button to try an add a second one.

Thanks.

Here is my code for the `ViewController`:

```
    class ViewController: UITableViewController {

        var testArray = [Category]()

        var sections: [Category] = CategoryData().getCategoryFromData()

        @IBAction func editButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            self.isEditing = !self.isEditing
        }

        @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        }

@IBAction func saveNewData(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if segue.sourceViewController is AddBookCategoryViewController {

        print("saveNewData")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return testArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testArray[section].sectionItems!.count
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookList", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = testArray[indexPath.section].sectionItems?[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(sections[indexPath.section].sectionItems?[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return testArray[section].sectionHeading
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.orange()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is the AddBookCategoryViewController:

```
import UIKit

class AddBookCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: Category?

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var pickCategory: UIButton!

    @IBAction func segmentedChangeFields(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            nameLabel.text = "Name of Book"
            authorLabel.text = "Author"
            authorLabel.isHidden = false
            authorTextField.isHidden = false
            pickCategory.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            nameLabel.text = "Name of Category"
            authorLabel.isHidden = true
            authorTextField.isHidden = true
            pickCategory.isHidden = true
            categoryLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var authorTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "saveNewData" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            print("1")

            if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                print("2")

                } else {
                print("3")
                vc.testArray.append(Category(sectionHeading: nameTextField.text!, sectionItems: []))
            }
        }
        print("4")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: to be sure: there is no way to get to prepare for segue second time? method is not called ever again?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I believe so because everything is printing to the logs as they are supposed to. I actually figured it out after doing some tinkering. It worked once I added tableView.reloadData() to the saveNewData action.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I managed to figure out the problem. I was able to add `tableView.reloadData()` to the `@IBAction func saveNewData` in the View Controller, like so.

```
@IBAction func saveNewData(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if segue.sourceViewController is AddBookCategoryViewController {

        print("saveNewData")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Thanks.